# All the functions defined for onClick of button are getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, onclick

I have below code in jsp and js. What's happening is irrespective of what button I am clicking both the javascript functions are getting called. I am not sure what am i missing here?

HTML:

```
<a type="button" id="scrollOffsetDiv" href="dashboard?offloglag=off&duration=${duration}#offset">Offset</a>

<a type="button" id="scrollMsgDiv" href="dashboard?offloglag=off&duration=${duration}#offset">Msg</a>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).on("click","#scrollOffsetDiv", setTimeout(scrollOffsetDiv,3000));
    function scrollOffsetDiv() {
        var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
            elementOffset = $('#offset').offset().top,
            scrollDistance      = (scrollTop-elementOffset);
        alert("2222222222");
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollDistance
        }, 200);
    }

    $(document).on("click","#scrollMsgDiv", setTimeout(scrollMsgDiv,3000));
    function scrollMsgDiv() {
        var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
            elementOffset = $('#msgsbytesinpersec').offset().top,
            scrollDistance      = (scrollTop-elementOffset);
        alert("33333333");
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: scrollDistance
        }, 200);
    }
```

Adding [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xknegdnL/) link.

Comment: I don't see any issues in your code. Do you have a live link for us to test? JSFiddle?

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but your links will redirect to `dashboard?offloglag=off&duration=${duration}#offset` before your functions get fired (after your 3 second delay).

Comment: It's otherwise. After the redirect the scroll will happen

Comment: Please provide a link to some live code or add a Snippet to your question so we can test.

Comment: updated the question with jsfiddle link

Comment: what if you wrap your setTimeout on function(e){e.preventDefault();setTimeout(....)}

Comment: @chepe263 , this works. thanks! But is there anyway I can retain css for the button. After I use e.preventDefault() the css to be used after button click doesn't works.

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` pretty much is making the link not act like a link, so your not getting the `:active` or `:visited` states. If you're okay with the page redirecting to `dashboard`, then you can remove that `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: after I remove e.preventDefault() function inside setTimeOut are not called.

Comment: remove preventDefault() and add return true at the end of the function http://jsfiddle.net/chepe263/xknegdnL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working with this jQuery code:

```
$("#scrollOffsetDiv").click(function(){ setTimeout(scrollOffsetDiv,3000); });
function scrollOffsetDiv() {
    alert("2222222222");
}

$("#scrollMsgDiv").click(function() { setTimeout(scrollMsgDiv,3000) });
function scrollMsgDiv() {
    alert("33333333");
}
```

Though I believe the main issue was simply needing to wrap your `setTimeout` function in a `function(){}`. Doing without that wrapper seems to only work with not parameterized calls to a function... if your calling a function with variables, wrap it in `function(){}`.

Anyone want to improve my vocabulary on the issue, please feel free. I've only learned this through observation.

An even more elegant way to write it might be:

```
$("#scrollOffsetDiv").click(function(){ setTimeout(function(){
    var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $('#offset').offset().top,
        scrollDistance      = (scrollTop-elementOffset);
    alert("2222222222");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollDistance
    }, 200);
},3000); });

$("#scrollMsgDiv").click(function() { setTimeout(function(){
    var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
        elementOffset = $('#msgsbytesinpersec').offset().top,
        scrollDistance      = (scrollTop-elementOffset);
    alert("33333333");
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollDistance
    }, 200);
},3000) });
```

Comment: For some reason "$("#scrollOffsetDiv").click()" is not working in my code.

Comment: Define "not working". Do you have the console up to see if it's throwing errors? Here's the working fiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/xknegdnL/1/

Comment: i don't see any errors. But the function itself is not getting called. I tried using e.preventDefault() (suggested by @chepe263) and it works. only drawback is it also removes the css for the button.

Comment: I'm getting an error with your updated code: `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`. You don't have any element in your HMTL called `#offset`. What browser are you testing on? You definitely should be getting errors. (On Chrome, I hit F12 and click the "Console" tab.)